# Detect Iphone 6 by mac on wifi network if its not connected.

Tags: iphone, ios8, wifi

I want to track my **iPhone 6s** device for the probe requests it is sending to connect to the WiFi router.

This is my current setup:

I have kept the WiFi on and have forgotten the network, in the phone so that it probes new APs.

> 1.The location and services is disabled.
>
> 2.The Mobile-Data is also On.
>
> 3.I am using Aircrack-ng to trace the probe requests to the router.
>
> 4.I ran the setup to get the probe requests for 1 hour, but still couldn't get the entry for the iPhone.
>
> 5.I also used wireshark and a different router to detect the iPhone but still it is not available. The capture duration was 1 hour.
>
> 6.The phone screen was randomly on and off.

I have read that from iOS8 Apple uses MAC randomization for the user safety so that they can't be tracked, but now I have a clear insight of what are the conditions when the randomization occurs(location disabled and packet data disabled and phone in sleep mode.)

I want to know that is the randomization actually happening and even if it is happening, how do I know the new Locally Randomized address of my device to trace it on Aircrack-ng/Wireshark.

And If the randomization process is actually not happening then why can't I see my iPhone in the list.

Some articles I followed:

http://blog.mojonetworks.com/ios8-mac-randomization-analyzed/.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/controller/technotes/8-0/iPhone_roam/b_iPhone-roaming.html#concept_79EB523637BD49F3AE876F9C1C95DD69

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Eventhough I couldn't figure out how the randomization works or when it randomizes but I did reach to a conclusion that the randomized Mac has the second nibble of most significant byte as 2. So I detect that whether it is randomized Mac or not and then leave it out.